# VB and MariaDB SQL

Tags: sql, vb.net, mariadb

It giving me error - **System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'**

```
       Dim cmdtText As String = "SELECT StaffID, StaffFName, StaffLName, StaffCity FROM Staff WHERE StaffID =   @StaffID" _
        & " OR StaffFName  =  @StaffFName " _
        & " OR StaffLName  =  @StaffLName " _
        & " OR StaffCity   =  @StaffCity "

        cmde.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", MySqlDbType.Int64, 11).Value = 
         txtID.Text
        cmde.Parameters.Add("@StaffFName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
         txtFName.Text.ToString
        cmde.Parameters.Add("@StaffLName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
         txtLName.Text.ToString
        cmde.Parameters.Add("@StaffCity", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = 
         txtCity.Text.ToString
```

If I use one parameter at a time it works. Without using OR

```
          Dim cmdtText As String = "SELECT StaffID, StaffFName, StaffLName, 
          StaffCity FROM Staff WHERE StaffCity  =  @StaffCity "
```

If I use search with ID as input it works.

Comment: You've got a much bigger problem than a syntax error. You absolutely must use parameterized queries to prevent sql injection attacks. There's no excuse for building an sql command from strings and textbox values.

Comment: Post the *actual* error produced by this code. You wouldn't get a syntax error with specific values if you used parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this command parameter SQL parameter input type to text and it works.
It does not like me using MySqlDbType.Int64
It's working but I don't understand it as ID is int type in my database.

cmde.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", **MySqlDbType.Text**, 11).Value = txtID.Text